# Create a loop to plot graphs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID   Product    Yield     Time
3    XC         0.88      2020-01-02
4    XB         1.0       2020-01-03
5    XC         0.2       2020-01-04
...
```

What I want to do is plot the yield over time for every of my 270 products.
Is there a way to do a loop?

I tried this:

```
for i in df['Product']:

 g=i.plot.scatter(x='Time',y='Yield',legend=None)
 hfont = {'fontname':'Arial'}
 g.set_xlabel("Time",fontweight='bold',**hfont,size=13)
 plt.xticks(rotation=90)
 g.set_ylabel("Yield",fontweight='bold',**hfont, size=13)
 plt.show
```

But it gives me the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'plot'

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In `for i in df['Product']` what do you think here `i` is? Isn't it string?

Comment: yes I  get that i is a string - but that does not help me on how to solve it and get the products instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the rows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   g=i.plot.scatter(x=row['Time'],y=row['Yield'],legend=None)
   hfont = {'fontname':'Arial'}
   g.set_xlabel("Time",fontweight='bold',**hfont,size=13)
   plt.xticks(rotation=90)
   g.set_ylabel("Yield",fontweight='bold',**hfont, size=13)
   plt.show
```

But each graph will have only one point...

Comment: hmmm..ok. Is there a possibility to query the products? What I did before was: ```product603=df.query('Product in ["product_603"]')```- maybe it is possible to loop over this?